# How to discribe object with computed properties in swagger (nestjs, typescript)?

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs

I have some DTO as below and I need to describe the DTO for Swagger:

```
{
  name: string;
  age: number;
  hobbies: { // maybe set of any hobbies 
    running: HobbyDto,
    swiming: HobbyDto,
    ...
  }
}
```

I need to describe the object and it should be as bellow:

```
{
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  age: number;

  @ApiProperty() // <- how to decorate this object?
  hobbies: { 
    [key: string]: HobbyDto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add another DTO class and use nested validate like this below:

```
@ApiProperty()
@ValidateNested({ each: true })
@Type(() => HobbiesDto)
hobbies: HobbiesDto[];
```

Comment: In this case I'm getting array of objects HobbyDto, but I need to get object, which of its properties has HobbyDto type.

Comment: yeah, you can use like this, 
```
class HobbyDto {
  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @IsString()
  running: string;

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @IsString()
  swimming: string;
}

{
...

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @IsOptional()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => HobbyDto)
  hobbies: HobbyDto;
...
}
```
this will show like this `"hobbies": {
    "running": "string",
    "swimming": "string"
  },`
in swagger

Comment: sorry I don't know how to format it in the comment place